# int array or string array or im wrong

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to put date&time into the array but im getting the error since i cannot put date/time with or just variables, i have tried changing the array of int to string but im getting the error that it cannot be resolved into a variable

```
private static void listM() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Here is the list of Movie(s) to select from," // gives user a list of movies to choose from
                + "\nPlease enter its respective ID:\n"
                + "1. Captain America\t|2. Toy Story\t|3. Jumanji\n4. Black Panther\t|"
                + "5. Green Lantern\t|6. Detective Pikachu\n7. Thor\t|8. 2012\t|9. Geostorm\n");

                 System.out.println("");
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  //use scanner to get ID of Movie  

         System.out.print("Input the ID of the Movies to view their information: ");
         int idmovie = scanner.nextInt();

            String[] movie = new String[9];   //make an array to store the movie information
            movie[0] = test;
            movie[1] = Captain;
            movie[2] = xxx;
            movie[3] = xxx;
            movie[4] = xxx;
            movie[5] = xxx;
            movie[6] = xxx;
            movie[7] = xxx;
            movie[8] = xxx;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the complete code snippet and the error you get. BTW, you cannot use `String` without double quotations, also java is a strongly typed language then you must consider data types before using them, for example you cannot store `int` directly into a `String` array without conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotes around strings. When you write `movie[0] = test;`, java will try to put the value of a variable named `test` into the movie array. Because you don't have a variable named test defined, Java will throw the error you are getting.

Here is how you probably want to define your array:

```java
movie[0] = "test";
```